# how to sum Total in multi level array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I have this array and I need the sum of `Total`:

```
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Code] => 1
                    [Total] => 28.56
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Code] => 2
                    [Total] => 67.99
                )

        )
```

I tried something like this:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value)
{
   $sum+= $value;
}
echo $sum;
```

but it returned a number in new line not summing it

The result should be `96.55`
Please help!

Comment: $sum+= $value->Total;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array listed looks like object.You can try this:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value)
{
   $sum+= $value->Total;
}
echo $sum;
```

[DEMO USING A SAMPLE DATA](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5cc497fc6803516b39a66c891a5bfaf932ffcf83)

Comment: returns me 0 for  first example

Comment: @IngusGraholskis you can `echo $value->Total;` and check what it is printing  or can post the sample data.

Comment: @IngusGraholskis you can try the added demo.

Comment: @IngusGraholskis check what you are missing or post the xml data.

Comment: Oh . .. Got it working kinda .. But It show correct answer 2 times in table

Comment: @IngusGraholskis see if you are echoing $sum on two places.

Answer (score 2):

Access the property Total from the object like `$sum+= $value->Total;`

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value)
{
   $sum+= $value->Total;
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to sum multidimensional array.

```
echo array_sum(array_map(function($item) { return $tempArray->Total; }, $tempArray));
```

Here, array_map function will map the `$tempArray->Total` in multidimensional array.

`array_sum` will sum the mapped values.

Comment: @Ingus Graholskis, in this case you can use array instead of object.